# How do you change the data table rolling join condition from weak inequality to strict inequality?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the two following two datasets, with a '`time`' column which represents a general timestamp, integers are used for simplicity of illustrating the example:

```
library(data.table)

df_test_1 <- 
    data.table(time = c(1:10, seq(20, 30, by = 5))) %>%
df_test_1$values <- -df_test_1$time
df_test_1 <- setkey(df_test_1, time)

df_test_2 <-
    data.table(time = c(15, 20, 26, 28, 31))
df_test_2 <- setkey(df_test_2, time)
```

so that:

```
> df_test_1
    time values
 ...
 5:    5     -5
 6:    6     -6
 7:    7     -7
 8:    8     -8
 9:    9     -9
10:   10    -10
11:   20    -20
12:   25    -25
13:   30    -30
```

and:

```
> df_test_2

   time
1:   15
2:   20
3:   26
4:   28
5:   31
```

The rolling join `df_test_1[df_test_2, roll = -Inf]` produces:

```
> df_test_1[df_test_2, roll = -Inf]
   time values
1:   15    -20
2:   20    -20
3:   26    -30
4:   28    -30
5:   31     NA
```

That is, for each `time` value in `df_test_1`, find all `time` values in `df_test_2` **smaller than or equal to it**, and associate the corresponding `value` to this row of `df_test_2`. For example, `df_test_1$time == 20` matches the time values `15` and `20` in `df_test_2$time`, thus the corresponding value of `-20` is associated to these rows of `df_test_2`.

I would like to change the join condition (in bold above) to **smaller than it**, that is, the answer produced should be:

```
   time values
1:   15    -20
2:   20    -25
3:   26    -30
4:   28    -30
5:   31     NA
```

The difference here is that the value at `df_test_1$time == 25` should be matched to the row of `df_test_2` where `df_test_2$time == 20`.

An alternate way of producing the desired result would be to take away a minuscule portion from `time`:

```
df_test_3 <-
    df_test_1 %>%
    mutate(time = time - 0.1) %>%
    setkey(time)
```

so that:

```
> df_test_3[df_test_2, roll = -Inf]
   time values
1:   15    -20
2:   20    -25
3:   26    -30
4:   28    -30
5:   31     NA
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run on my computer, since `data.table(time = c(1:10, seq(20, 30, by = 5))) %>%
    mutate(values = -time)` is not a data.table, so you can't set its key...

Comment: ah, ok, interesting, that must be some clash between `dplyr` and `data.table`. I will make it `dplyr` agnostic. Note the original code runs fine with my versions... `dplyr version 0.4.3` and `data.table version 1.9.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new `non-equi` joins feature in the current development version of data.table, this is straightforward:

```
# v1.9.7+
df_test_1[df_test_2, on=.(time > time), mult="first"]
```

Keyed joins are capable of only *equi* joins. `on` argument is essential for *conditional* joins.

Note that there's no need for data.tables to be *keyed* if the `on` argument is used. Even if you wish to key the data.tables, specifying `on` is better as it helps understand the code immediately at a later point.

See the installation instructions for devel version [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).