# R: Finding the closest of two dates according to an index column

Tags: r, date, datetime

The purpose of this project is to measure the time interval between a medical lab check and the most recent dose of a medication. Each patient has a different number of subsequent doses of this medication, and the number of follow-up lab checks are also different for each subject.

The first data frame contains study_id and respective dose dates:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

study_id<- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
dose_dt <- c('1/1/00', '2/1/00', '3/1/00', '1/1/01', '2/1/01', '1/1/02')
doses_df <- data.frame(study_id, dose_dt)
doses_df$dose_dt <- mdy(doses_df$dose_dt)
print(doses_df)

 study_id    dose_dt
1        1 2000-01-01
2        1 2000-02-01
3        1 2000-03-01
4        2 2001-01-01
5        2 2001-02-01
6        3 2002-01-01
```

The second data frame has matching study_id, this time with lab check dates and associated lab value and an indicator of abnormal (yes/no).

```r
study_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
lab_dt <- c('1/1/99', '3/1/00', '4/1/00', '2/1/01', '2/1/02', '3/1/02', '4/1/02')
lab_result <- c(100, 200, 50, 25, 75, 100, 75)
lab_abn_yn <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
labs_df <- data.frame(study_id, lab_dt, lab_result, lab_abn_yn)
labs_df$lab_dt <- mdy(labs_df$lab_dt)
print(labs_df)

  study_id     lab_dt lab_result lab_abn_yn
1        1 1999-01-01        100          0
2        1 2000-03-01        200          0
3        1 2000-04-01         50          1
4        2 2001-02-01         25          1
5        3 2002-02-01         75          1
6        3 2002-03-01        100          0
7        3 2002-04-01         75          1
```

Notice that subject 1 has one lab check that is in the past prior to the first medication dose, subject 2 has more doses than lab checks, and subject 3 has fewer doses than lab checks.

I want R to determine the date of the most recent dose of the medication prior to the lab check so that I can calculate the interval between dose and lab check. The output would preserve the lab values and indicators. Preferably, lab checks prior to the first dose (negative time interval from dose to lab check) would be reported as NA, but I can easily filter out negative time intervals. I also know how to use lubridate to calculate time intervals, so need to add that to the explanation.

Desired output:

```r
  study_id lab_dt     most_recent_dose_dt lab_result lab_abn_yn interval_months
     <dbl> <chr>      <chr>               <chr>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1        1 1999-01-01 NA                  NA                 NA          NA    
2        1 2000-03-01 2000-02-02          200                 0           0.966
3        1 2000-04-01 2000-03-01          50                  1           1    
4        2 2001-02-01 2001-01-01          25                  1           1    
5        3 2002-02-01 2002-01-01          75                  1           1    
6        3 2002-03-01 2002-01-01          100                 0           2    
7        3 2002-04-01 2002-01-01          75                  1           3
```

I've tried a number of merging schemes, but none preserve all data. There are ~40,000 subjects, so doing this by hand isn't feasible. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in three steps:

1. Filter to keep only doses that happened after the lab date
2. Filter to keep only the dose that was the most recent for each lab date (which is now the most recent dose thanks to the first filter)
3. Join back onto the list of labs to re-include lab dates that had no prior doses

Note that your sample data isn't quite as printed in the desired out, in that Feb 1st became Feb 2nd for the second observation.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
doses_df <- tibble(
  study_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3),
  dose_dt = mdy(c("1/1/00", "2/1/00", "3/1/00", "1/1/01", "2/1/01", "1/1/02"))
)
labs_df <- tibble(
  study_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  lab_dt = mdy(c("1/1/99", "3/1/00", "4/1/00", "2/1/01", "2/1/02", "3/1/02", "4/1/02")),
  lab_result = c(100, 200, 50, 25, 75, 100, 75),
  lab_abn_yn = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
)

most_recent_doses <- labs_df %>%
  left_join(doses_df, by = "study_id") %>%
  group_by(study_id, lab_dt) %>%
  filter(dose_dt < lab_dt) %>%
  filter(dose_dt == max(dose_dt)) %>%
  select(study_id, lab_dt, dose_dt)

labs_df %>%
  left_join(most_recent_doses, by = c("study_id", "lab_dt")) %>%
  mutate(interval_months = interval(dose_dt, lab_dt) / months(1))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 6
#>   study_id lab_dt     lab_result lab_abn_yn dose_dt    interval_months
#>      <dbl> <date>          <dbl>      <dbl> <date>               <dbl>
#> 1        1 1999-01-01        100          0 NA                      NA
#> 2        1 2000-03-01        200          0 2000-02-01               1
#> 3        1 2000-04-01         50          1 2000-03-01               1
#> 4        2 2001-02-01         25          1 2001-01-01               1
#> 5        3 2002-02-01         75          1 2002-01-01               1
#> 6        3 2002-03-01        100          0 2002-01-01               2
#> 7        3 2002-04-01         75          1 2002-01-01               3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I like `dplyr` really much, but there I find `data.table` more powerfull

Comment: non-equi joins are a longstanding feature that dplyr doesn't have, certainly. But for common small data cases where generating the product of the two datasets is not going to be prohibitive, I find it useful to recognise that you can achieve the desired result without such joins. `data.table` is always nice for millions of rows :)

Comment: Perfect it works, thanks! It was that jedi-tier double group_by before the filtering that I was leaving out. I always forget the utility of multiple-entry group_by's. Thanks also to denis. I was thinking a rolling join might be in the future of this problem, but I couldn't quite figure out how to make it happen. Thanks to you both. This will be enormously helpful with this project which is trying to make sense of a massive (IRB approved) EMR data dump. Cheers, Casey

Comment: @CalumYou I totally agree with you, and actually it cost me a lot of time to understand properly this join, when the dplyr approach you propose is easier to understand I think.

Answer (score 3):

There is a one line solution with `data.table`, using `non-equi` joins:

```
library(data.table)
# create data.tables
labs_df <-  setDT(labs_df)
doses_df <- setDT(doses_df)

# create join variable
doses_df[,join_time := dose_dt]
labs_df[,join_time := lab_dt]

# do nonequi join with a condition
doses_df[labs_df,on=.(study_id,join_time < join_time),mult = "last"]

   study_id    dose_dt  join_time     lab_dt lab_result lab_abn_yn
1:        1       <NA> 1999-01-01 1999-01-01        100          0
2:        1 2000-02-01 2000-03-01 2000-03-01        200          0
3:        1 2000-03-01 2000-04-01 2000-04-01         50          1
4:        2 2001-01-01 2001-02-01 2001-02-01         25          1
5:        3 2002-01-01 2002-02-01 2002-02-01         75          1
6:        3 2002-01-01 2002-03-01 2002-03-01        100          0
7:        3 2002-01-01 2002-04-01 2002-04-01         75          1
```

Here the idea is that you are merging doses_df on the `study_id` and `join_time` of `labs_df` that respect the condition `join_time` from the dose_df < `joint_time` from the labs_df.

I create a `join_time` column because the join only keep one of the two time column otherwise and changes names, so I always get confuse: if you do directly

```
doses_df[labs_df,on=.(study_id,dose_dt < lab_dt),mult = "last"]
```

It gives you

```
   study_id    dose_dt lab_result lab_abn_yn
1:        1 1999-01-01        100          0
2:        1 2000-03-01        200          0
3:        1 2000-04-01         50          1
4:        2 2001-02-01         25          1
5:        3 2002-02-01         75          1
6:        3 2002-03-01        100          0
7:        3 2002-04-01         75          1
```

which is right for the `lab_result` and other column, but confusing for the `dose_dt` column because it becomes the `lab_dt` column you did the merge on (the merge is like sub-setting the `doses_dt` column on the `lab_dt` values).

I actually wanted to use rolling joins in the beginning :

```
doses_df[labs_df,on=.(study_id,join_time),roll = T]

   study_id    dose_dt  join_time     lab_dt lab_result lab_abn_yn
1:        1       <NA> 1999-01-01 1999-01-01        100          0
2:        1 2000-03-01 2000-03-01 2000-03-01        200          0
3:        1 2000-03-01 2000-04-01 2000-04-01         50          1
4:        2 2001-02-01 2001-02-01 2001-02-01         25          1
5:        3 2002-01-01 2002-02-01 2002-02-01         75          1
6:        3 2002-01-01 2002-03-01 2002-03-01        100          0
7:        3 2002-01-01 2002-04-01 2002-04-01         75          1
```

but the problem is that it keeps date equal or inferior to.

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112514/how-do-you-change-the-data-table-rolling-join-condition-from-weak-inequality-to) to find the equi-joins solution, and I recommend [this tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/understanding-data-table-rolling-joins/) for the rolling joins.
`data.table` is fast, and allow you to do in one line what you actually want (take the last line in the merge that comply with `dose_dt < lab_dt`).

Comment: Thanks again, and for the turorial as well,C

Comment: No pb, I actually had to do the same for the same kind of data one month ago (patient visit and lab results), so it was still fresh in my mind and it was great to explain it.